# Dust.js as client side template supports CDN, isn't Angular client site template also support CDN?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, dust.js

I am working on Single page application and decided to go with following tech stack.

```
1. Nodejs as server side
2. Angularjs as client side
3. Dustjs as server side template (only for index.html)
```

However during my discussion with team; everyone is insisting to use dust.js for client side as well. Main reason for forcing dustjs template for client side is because CDN support for dustjs template files.

My understanding is; if i use absolute URL in my Angular directive and give CDN path for Angular client side template then isn't it with Angularjs as well I would be able to support CDN?

Please advice.

Comment: I believe cross domain call will be a problem with angular templates though you need to set some configuration to work with the CDN in angular templates though ..more details you can find at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19995177/639406

Comment: Thanks...at least seems like we can use CDN for Angularjs template.