# Angular load ng-includes doesnt work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to include my template file with angular mode.
like this

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 member-container bg-light-green" ng-include="'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/link.com/frontend-web/app/views/login.html'">
```

It's working in Firefox, but not in Safari, Chrome. When I look at the console, it's look like this

```
"<!-- <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 member-container bg-light-green" ng-include="'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/link.com/frontend-web/app/views/login.html'"> -->"
```

Comment: are you trying to load a template from a different location than your server?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Yeah, I think so :)

Comment: As I say... It's work great in Firefox... but not on Chrome, Safari...

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe or not, The link "amazonaws" is a server link, there my template's are

Comment: Your question has already an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994161/how-do-i-get-ng-include-directive-to-work-with-a-content-delivery-network

Comment: I already have that.. It's not working anyway :/ @DeblatonJean-Philippe

Comment: Official docs says : ``loading templates from a different domain won't work on all browsers.``